# I am not able to truncate Table as it fails with error related to replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to TRUNCATE TABLE but it fails with following error  `Cannot truncate table 'Subscriptions' because it is published for replication or enabled for Change Data Capture.`

not sure how to resolve this error, this issue is with MS SQL SERVER 2014

i looked for this  google but didnt not find any clear answer one example https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1701086-2799-1.aspx

https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=80545

Is there a simple solution as i don't have administrative privilege to database as this is hosted with thirdparty

Comment: Can you delete instead of truncate?

Comment: Can do that as i am not sure if i can recreate Table so dont want to take any changes with that, another option could be to create a different table first with same data and then try to delete the main table & rename the second one to actual name. and to be honest i want to know why this error is coming and what could be the resolution without deleting table

Comment: I don't mean dropping the table, I mean using `DELETE FROM mytable;`

Answer (score 4):

Truncate cannot be used in certain cases like replication / foreign key contraints, etc.

As per [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) you need to use delete.

> **Restrictions**
>
> You cannot use TRUNCATE TABLE on tables that:
>
> Are referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint. (You can truncate a table
>   that has a foreign key that references itself.)
>
> Participate in an indexed view.
>
> Are published by using transactional replication or merge replication.
>
> For tables with one or more of these characteristics, use the DELETE
>   statement instead.
>
> TRUNCATE TABLE cannot activate a trigger because the operation does
>   not log individual row deletions. For more information, see CREATE
>   TRIGGER (Transact-SQL).
>
> In Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Parallel Data Warehouse:
>
> TRUNCATE TABLE is not allowed within the EXPLAIN statement.
>
> TRUNCATE TABLE cannot be ran inside of a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the below link for this error.

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/25/sql-server-cdc-and-truncate-cannot-truncate-table-because-it-is-published-for-replication-or-enabled-for-change-data-capture/

It clearly states the conditions when this error comes and how it can be resolved i.e. by disabling "Change Data Capture" on that table.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use `DELETE FROM <tablename>`

Comment: Can you add more details about how the proposed code addresses the problem? Code-only answers are not very helpful, neither for the asker, nor others.

Comment: TRUNCATE is DDL command while DELETE is DML. So TRUNCATE resets the identity of a table and this will throw errors. I hope this explanation helps

Comment: Can you add the details to the answer? Thanks,